# Slicing n-dimensional Array with Slice Object

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Let's say we have a n=3-dimensional numpy array `arr` which may be sliced like so: `arr[:2,:,:6]`.
What would be the equivalent of doing such a slicing via a slice object? 
Explicitly, define:

```
slice_obj = slice(?) # From my understanding, slice is for 1D slicing - Might be a more complicated object
```

So:

```
numpy.array_equal(arr[:2,:,:6],arr[slice_obj]) == True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer. Use a tuple of slice objects:

```
slice_obj = (slice(2),slice(None),slice(6))
```